# Mongodb updating timestamp to date from exisiting document

Tags: mongodb, datetime, timestamp, mongodb-query

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54ec60dae4b07e1ee10a899d"),
    "_class" : "com.lybrate.core.phoenix.event.PhxEventTracking",
    "rfpId" : "198163",
    "eventType" : "QnA",
    "eventId" : "49548",
    "paramType" : "S",
    "timestamp" : NumberLong("1424777434982"),
    "utm_source" : "email",
    "utm_medium" : "gw",
    "utm_content" : "null",
    "utm_term" : "null",
    "utm_campaign" : "Email_050215_gw_askq",
    "referrer" : "https://www.lybrate.com/questions/ask",
    "source" : "PS-AQP",
    "e_stat" : "rejected ",
    "a_time" : NumberLong("1424802600000"),
    "newdDate" : ISODate("0NaN-NaN-NaNTNaN:NaN:NaNZ"),
    "newDate" : ISODate("2015-03-27T08:32:31.679Z")
}
```

I have this MongoDB document and I want to update the newDate to the value of timestamp in the db I am using a single mongodb query as below

```
db.phxEventTracking.update({"eventType":"QnA"},{$set:{newDate:new ISODate(this.timestamp)}},{upsert:false,multi:true})
```

but this updates the newDate to current time and not the dateTime value of timestamp...Answers would be appreciated..thanks and regards..:)

Answer (score 0):

I've double checked the functionality of your code and it appears that, when you pass the `this.timestamp` parameter, `this` will refer to the global scope (similar to `window` in JavaScript).

I've also tried inserting random elements in a collection, with various variable names instead of timestamp:

```
db.test.insert({ date: new ISODate(this.variable1) });

db.test.insert({ date: new ISODate(this.variable2) });
```

Since those variables are undefined, the ISODate wrapper interprets that there are no parameters passed, thus calling `new ISODate()`, which returns the current timestamp.

Below is the code for the `ISODate function`, as logged in the `mongo` shell:

```
function (isoDateStr){
    if (!isoDateStr)
        return new Date();

    var isoDateRegex = /(\d{4})-?(\d{2})-?(\d{2})([T ](\d{2})(:?(\d{2})(:?(\d{2}(\.\d+)?))?)?(Z|([+-])(\d{2}):?(\d{2})?)?)?/;
    var res = isoDateRegex.exec(isoDateStr);

    if (!res)
        throw "invalid ISO date";

    var year = parseInt(res[1],10) || 1970; // this should always be present
    var month = (parseInt(res[2],10) || 1) - 1;
    var date = parseInt(res[3],10) || 0;
    var hour = parseInt(res[5],10) || 0;
    var min = parseInt(res[7],10) || 0;
    var sec = parseInt((res[9] && res[9].substr(0,2)),10) || 0;
    var ms = Math.round((parseFloat(res[10]) || 0) * 1000);
    if (ms == 1000) {
        ms = 0;
        ++sec;
    }
    if (sec == 60) {
        sec = 0;
        ++min;
    }
    if (min == 60) {
        min = 0;
        ++hour;
    }
    if (hour == 24) {
        hour = 0;   // the day wrapped, let JavaScript figure out the rest
        var tempTime = Date.UTC(year, month, date, hour, min, sec, ms);
        tempTime += 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;    // milliseconds in a day
        var tempDate = new Date(tempTime);
        year = tempDate.getUTCFullYear();
        month = tempDate.getUTCMonth();
        date = tempDate.getUTCDate();
    }

    var time = Date.UTC(year, month, date, hour, min, sec, ms);

    if (res[11] && res[11] != 'Z'){
        var ofs = 0;
        ofs += (parseInt(res[13],10) || 0) * 60*60*1000; // hours
        ofs += (parseInt(res[14],10) || 0) *    60*1000; // mins
        if (res[12] == '+') // if ahead subtract
            ofs *= -1;

        time += ofs
    }

    return new Date(time);
}
```